# Include the www prefix when adding a site to Google Webmaster Central?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I am wondering if I should add the www prefix when I add a website to Google Webmaster Central. Both versions of the website (**http://www.website.com** and **http://website.com**) are exactly the same so I am wondering if it makes a difference.

Comment: Questions about website administration are better served on [Pro Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose one and only one version so search engines wouldn't be confused if your site is with www or not. I personally like without www but it really makes no difference.

Then make a redirect adding this code to .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoursite\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ http://yoursite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then mark it in Google Webmaster tools.

It's not very good when half your backlinks go to www.yoursite.com and half of backlinks to yoursite.com

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned already, a domain without www will be seen as a subdomain/page. Even worse the 2 versions (with & without www) will result in duplicate content hence loosing points from Google.

You can do what Ruel & How said above but I also recommend adding a canonical meta tag which tells the search engine which page should be indexed, e.g. this means www.domain.com, domain.com, www/domain.com/index will all be treated the same rather than 4 duplicate pages.

Try to stick with www. as many places where you submit a link for your site will ask you to include www, thus your www. version of your page will get all the SEO rankings. Stick with one or your Page Rank will be split between the 2 versions.

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you, some likes websites with **www** because it makes the site look professional, and some likes **without www** because its shorter.

You can only use one though. Set a redirect on your choice. If you chose with **www**, set a redirect that redirects **http://example.com** to **http://www.example.com** and vice versa.

Comment: Google seems to recently have gotten confused with redirecting robots.txt - you might want to set up your webserver to serve a "Disallow /" to the non-preferred domain.

Answer (score 1):

"www" is actually a subdomain. I you add example.com, you covered all subdomains, eg blog.example.com. If you verify www.example.com, you need to add blog.example.com later, not sure about WT, this is generally this way.